# I need help negating this logic

Tags: if-statement, boolean-logic

What is the opposite of `(previous = 4 || previous = 5) && current = 2`?

I know I can just write it as `!((previous = 4 || previous = 5) && current = 2)`, but now it's turned into something that will hunt me until I find the answer. How do you distribute the negative within the parenthesis?

This is what I'm thinking but it doesn't seem right to me.

`!((previous = 4 || previous = 5) && current = 2`

`!(previous = 4 || previous = 5) || current != 2`

`(previous != 4 && previous != 5) || current != 2`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: That's correct. Think about it. In the original, `previous` had to be either 4 or 5, or the whole thing was false. So in the opposite, as long as `previous` *isn't* 4 or 5, it won't matter what the value of `current` is.

Comment: I guess it makes more sense to me if I write it out as `current != 2 || (previous != 4 && previous != 5)`. This way it read as `This is true when current is anything other than two, but if current is two then previous cannot be 4 and previous cannot be 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeMorgan's Law states that when you take the complement of an expression (that is, when you negate it), you can simply swap all OR's and AND's and negate every term to get the desired result.

For example

```
!(A && B) = !A || !B

!(A || B) = !A && !B

!(A && !B) = !A || B
```

therefore, applying these two simple rules,

```
!((previous = 4 || previous = 5) && current = 2) 
=
!(previous = 4 || previous = 5) || current != 2
=
(previous != 4 && previous != 5) || current != 2
```

(broken up over multiple lines because one line was too long)

Note that above, because we had an expression as one of the terms, we applied DeMorgan's Law recursively (twice, to be exact).

Some more examples

```
!(A > B || A + B == 0) = A <= B && A + B != 0

!(A >= 2 && A < 8) = A < 2 || A >= 8
```

Comment: `!((previous = 4 || previous = 5) && current = 2)`
goes to
`!(previous = 4 || previous = 5) || current != 2`
goes to
`previous != 4 && previous != 5 || current != 2`...
More or less the same result, given order of operations.

Comment: j.i.h. - Indeed, AND does take precedence over OR, so the parentheses become redundant in this particular case. However, I think leaving them intact helps to clarify this procedure. If instead we were negating the expression `((A == 4 && B == 5) || C == 2)`, the parentheses would matter.

Comment: I just had to double check because you skip the middle step, but the end result is correct.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. I'll add in the additional step :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer using this equation `!(a && b) = !a || !b`

So step by step:

```
!((previous = 4 || previous = 5) && current = 2)
!(previous = 4 || previous = 5) || !(current = 2)
(previous != 4 && previous != 5) || current != 2
```